# Extract text from xml nodeset

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I'm pulling a date from a webpage and having a hard time extracting the text

```
date_ <- html_nodes(page_, xpath = '//*[@id="particular_con"]/div[2]/text()')
## prints ## 
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1]  2017-03-27
```

I tried adding ``` ``[[(1L) ``` or `date_[[1]]`
but this prints

```
{xml_node}
<text>
```

I want to extract just `2017-03-27`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `html_text`

As the function name says `html_nodes` returns the kinda pointers to the nodes. To extract information from them use `html_text` and `html_attr`

Change first line to:

```
date_ <- html_nodes(page_, xpath = '//*[@id="particular_con"]/div[2]/text()') %>% html_text()
```